# What are the similarities and differences between a lens in Haskell and destructuring in Clojure?

Tags: haskell, clojure, haskell-lens, lenses, destructuring

**Assumptions:**

- I want to parse a nested JSON String.
- I know that Haskell encourages solving problems with a type system, and Clojure eschews a type system, preferring to solve the problem with data structures.
- I'm aware that in both languages this process is referred to as *destructuring* - but it doesn't have another name in Clojure, whereas in Haskell this is also called *using a lens*, so I'm calling the Clojure one *destructuring*, and moving on

We can see that we can create a [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) [like this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

initialState :: Game
initialState = Game
    { _score = 0
    , _units =
        [ Unit
            { _health = 10
            , _position = Point { _x = 3.5, _y = 7.0 }
            }
        ]
    }

health :: Lens' Unit Int
health = lens _health (\unit v -> unit { _health = v })
```

It's purpose is to get the `health` value from the `game` data structure.

We can do destructuring [like this](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) in Clojure:

```
user=> (def book {:name "SICP" :details {:pages 657 :isbn-10 "0262011530"}})
#'user/book

user=> (let [{name :name {pages :pages isbn-10 :isbn-10} :details} book]
     (println "name:" name "pages:" pages "isbn-10:" isbn-10))
name: SICP pages: 657 isbn-10: 0262011530
```

The purpose is to get the nested values for name, pages etc from the nested structure.

In both cases you're coming up with a mechanism to reusably retrieve values from a nested structure.

My question is: **What are the similarities and differences between a lens in Haskell and destructuring in Clojure?**

Comment: Clojure's destructuring is actually more analogous to Pattern Matching in Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Clojure code would most closely be expressed like this in Haskell:

```
book :: Book
book = Book {name = "SICP", details = Details {pages = 657, isbn_10: "0262011530"}}

main = do
  let Book {name = name, details = Details {pages = pages, isbn_10 = isbn_10}} = book
  putStrLn $ "name:" ++ name ++ "pages:" ++ (show pages) ++ "isbn-10:" ++ isbn-10
```

Here we used Haskell's pattern matching, which is basically a more general form of Clojure's destructuring bind, to get at the contents of the record. This has nothing to do with lenses.

Now let's look at your Haskell code with lenses. This code has three record types, Game, Unit and Point, and those types each have an automatically-defined set of functions to access their members without pattern matching. These functions are called `_score`, `_health`, `_x` and so on (just like the member names). They take a `Game`, `Unit` or `Point` respectively and produce the value of their respective member. If these functions would have to be defined manually (which they don't because Haskell defines such functions for all record types automatically), it'd look like this:

```
_health (Unit {health = h}) = h
```

So far this still has nothing to do with lenses.

The lens in the code is `health`. It contains the function `_health` (which, as described, takes a `Unit` and produces its health) and the function `(\unit v -> unit { _health = v })`, which takes a unit and a value and produces a new unit whose health has been set to that value. In other words the lens contains the code to both get and set the health of a unit. The Lens library now contains various functions that you can use to compose and work with such lenses.

So to answer your question: There are no similarities between lenses and destructuring.

Comment: Yeah - fair enough - I'll give this one to you. I feel like I didn't ask the question properly.  I think the question I had in my mind was "What's the difference between a lens in Haskell and using a key sequence to access a nested structure in Clojure?" like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/240e024625923d99cfd6